# Pass the current location in Google API URL in JSP

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jsp

I am trying to print the distance between current location and given location(pass as argument from another page) .

Below is the URL which is printing fine but problem is that I have to give the source location manually in the URL. Is there any way in which current location automatically pick. Golocation is one option but how will I pass the value of current location in below URL and redirect to page automatically.

Please help.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=190%20London%20Rd,%20Newbury,%20West%20Berkshire%20RG14%202EW,%20UK&destinations=london&mode=transit&transit_mode=train&key=AIzaSyCeBdq7rr-R7w7vZCXscLWgEDb3oO9CUhw

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro) documentation, the required parameters are `origins`, `destinations` and `key`.

What you can do is to ask the user for provide his current location and set it as its `origins`, that way you're still able to meet the required parameters.